# swift OSX: serially generating files using GCD

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to generate .aiff files using NSSpeechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString() and am using GCd using a serial queue as NSSpeechSynthesizer takes in a string and creates an aiff file at a specified NSURL address. I used the standard for loop method for a list of strings in a [String:[String]] but this creates some files which have 0 bytes.

Here is the function to generate the speech:

```
    func createSpeech(type: String, name: String) {
        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath("\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/\(name).aiff"){
            do{
             try NSFileManager().createDirectoryAtPath("\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes:  nil)
let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/\(name).aiff")
                            print("Attempting to save speech \(name).aiff")
self.synth.startSpeakingString(name, toURL: URL)
            }catch{
                print("error occured")
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the function that traverses the dictionary to create the files:

```
        for key in self.nodeLibrary.keys{
                                dispatch_sync(GlobalBackgroundQueue){
                let type = self.nodeLibrary[key]?.0
            let name = key.componentsSeparatedByString("_")[0]
                                    if !speechCheck.contains(name){
mixer.createSpeech(type!, name: name)
                                    }
            }
        }
```

The globalBackgroundQueue is an alias to the GCD queue call _T for readability.

The routine runs fine, creates folders and subfolders as required by another external function then synthesizes the speech but in my case I always get one or some which don't load properly, giving 0 bytes or a too small number of bytes which makes the file unuseable.

I read the following post and have been using these GCD methods for a while but I'm not sure where I'm wrong here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Any help greatly appreciated as usual

edit: Updated with completion closure and found possibly a bug

I have created a closure function as below and use it in another helper method which checks for any errors such as sourceFile.length being 0 once loaded. However, all files exhibit a 0 length which is not possible as I checked each file's audio properties using finder's property command+i.

```
func synthesise(type: String, name: String, completion: (success: Bool)->()) {
        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath("\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/\(name).aiff"){
            do{
             try NSFileManager().createDirectoryAtPath("\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes:  nil)
                let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/\(name).aiff")
                let success = self.synth.startSpeakingString(name, toURL: URL)
                completion(success: success)
            }catch{
                print("error occured")
            }
        }
    }

    func loadSpeech(type: String, name: String){
            synthesise(type, name: name, completion: {(success: Bool)->Void in
                if success{
    print("File \(name) created successfully with return \(self.synthSuccess), checking file integrity")
                    let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(self.dataPath)\(type)/\(name)/\(name).aiff")
                    do{
                    let source = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL)
                        print("File has length: \(source.)")
                    }catch{
                        print("error loading file")
                    }
                }else{
                    print("creation unsuccessful, trying again")
    self.loadSpeech(type, name: name)
                }
            })
        }
```

The files are generated with their folders and both the method startSpeakingString->Bool and the delegate function I have in my class which updates the synthSuccess property show true. So I load an AVAudioFile to check its length. All file lengths are 0. Which they are not except for one.

When I say bug, this is from another part of the app where I load an AVAudioEngine and start loading buffers with the frameCount argument set to sourceAudioFile.length which gives a diagnostic error but this is out of context right now.

Comment: There are still issues in your edited code: 1. In your `synthesise` method, you are not completing _when_ the asynchronous task has been completed. Instead you immediately complete it after you _started_ the asynchronous task. Fix: you need to utilise the _delegate_ `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` in order to get notified _when_ the task has been finished. Then and only then call the completion handler. Secondly, you need to ensure that the completion handler will eventually be called. That is, it MUST be called eventually. In your `synthesise` method, you don't fulfil this requirement.

Comment: 2. `loadSpeech` does not work as you expect. Because of 1. it will not be called when synthesise fails. 3. You still need a way to ensure that multiple inputs will be called sequentially. Your method `loadSpeech ` happens to have already the basic structure to accomplish this. Create a new one with parameter of an array of inputs and a completion handler. The inner function has an inout parameter `Generator` and a completion handler. Call `gen.next`  in the inner function to get the next element in the array. When the task completed call the inner function passing it the generator.

Comment: Yes, I have both didFinishSpeaking and didEncounterError in my class file. I've made 3 different approahces, one using blocks, another with GCD and simple while checking a property I call finishedSpeak:Bool. No go. The while loop goes forever. However I also Tested one startSpeakingString without toURL and the messages print to the console. When I use toURL the message prints but the file is corrupted though no error message prints (which I have set as print("\(message) is the error"). I see other users having the same issue of having corrupted NSSpeechSynthesizer files,

Comment: According your description there seems to be a bug in the system frameworks. This really sounds unfortunate. You may now do the following: compose a minimal example that  demonstrates the issue and post a bug report. Alternatively, post the minimal example on SO as well and let us try to reproduce it and thus confirm that this is a bug in the systems frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startSpeakingString(_:toURL:)` will start an *asynchronous* task in the background. Effectively, your code starts a number of asynchronous tasks that run concurrently. This may be the cause of the problem that you experience.

A solution would need to ensure that only *one* task is active at a time.

The problem with `startSpeakingString(_:toURL:)` is, that it starts an asynchronous task - but the function *itself* provides no means to get notified when this task is finished.

However, there's a *delegate* which you need to setup in order to be notified.

So, your solution will require to define a [NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate/speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:).

You may want to create your own helper class that exposes an asynchronous function which has a completion handler:

```
func exportSpeakingString(string: String, url: NSURL, 
    completion: (NSURL?, ErrorType?) -> ())
```

Internally, the class creates an instance of `NSSpeechSynthesizer` *and* `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` and implements the delegate methods accordingly.

To complete the challenge, you need to search for an approach to run several asynchronous functions *sequentially*. There are already solutions on SO.

**Edit:**

I setup my own project to either confirm or neglect a possible issue in the `NSSpeechSynthesizer` system framework. So far, may own tests confirm that `NSSpeechSynthesizer` works as expected.

However, there are few subtleties worth mentioning:

1. Ensure you create a valid file URL which you pass as an argument to parameter `URL` in method `startSpeakingString(:toURL:)`.
2. Ensure you choose an extension for the output file which is known by `NSSpeechSynthesizer` and the system frameworks playing this file, for example `.aiff`.  Unfortunately, the documentation is quite lacking here - so I had to trial and error. The list of supported audio file formats by QuickTime may help here. Still, I have no idea how `NSSpeechSynthesizer` selects the output format.

The following two classes compose a simple easy to use library:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit


enum SpeechSynthesizerError: ErrorType {
    case ErrorActive
    case ErrorURL(message: String)
    case ErrorUnknown
}

internal class InternalSpeechSynthesizer: NSObject, NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    typealias CompletionFunc = (NSURL?, ErrorType?) -> ()

    private let synthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer(voice: nil)!
    private var _completion: CompletionFunc?
    private var _url: NSURL?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        synthesizer.delegate = self
    }

    // CAUTION: This call is not thread-safe! Ensure that multiple method invocations
    // will be called from the same thread!
    // Only _one_ task can be active at a time.
    internal func synthesize(input: String, output: NSURL, completion: CompletionFunc) {
        guard _completion == nil else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
                completion(nil, SpeechSynthesizerError.ErrorActive)
            }
            return
        }
        guard output.path != nil else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
                completion(nil, SpeechSynthesizerError.ErrorURL(message: "The URL must be a valid file URL."))
            }
            return
        }
        _completion = completion
        _url = output
        if !synthesizer.startSpeakingString(input, toURL: output) {
            fatalError("Could not start speeaking")
        }
    }


    internal func speechSynthesizer(sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                                    willSpeakWord characterRange: NSRange,
                                    ofString string: String)
    {
        NSLog("willSpeakWord")
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                                    willSpeakPhoneme phonemeOpcode: Int16)
    {
        NSLog("willSpeakPhoneme")
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                                    didEncounterErrorAtIndex characterIndex: Int,
                                    ofString string: String,
                                    message: String)
    {
        NSLog("didEncounterErrorAtIndex")
    }

    internal func speechSynthesizer(sender: NSSpeechSynthesizer,
                                    didFinishSpeaking finishedSpeaking: Bool)
    {
        assert(self._url != nil)
        assert(self._url!.path != nil)
        assert(self._completion != nil)
        var error: ErrorType?            
        if !finishedSpeaking {
            do {
                error = try self.synthesizer.objectForProperty(NSSpeechErrorsProperty) as? NSError
            } catch let err {
                error = err
            }
        } 
        let url: NSURL? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(self._url!.path!) ? self._url : nil        
        let completion = self._completion!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
            if url == nil && error == nil {
                error = SpeechSynthesizerError.ErrorUnknown
            }
            completion(url, error)
        }
        _completion = nil
        _url = nil
    }

}


public struct SpeechSynthesizer {
    public init() {}    
    private let _synthesizer = InternalSpeechSynthesizer()

    public func synthesize(input: String, output: NSURL, completion: (NSURL?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
        _synthesizer.synthesize(input, output: output) { (url, error) in
            completion(url, error)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as shown below:

```
func testExample() {
    let expect = self.expectationWithDescription("future should be fulfilled")

    let synth = SpeechSynthesizer()
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/Documents/speech.aiff")

    synth.synthesize("Hello World!", output: url) { (url, error) in
        if let url = url {
            print("URL: \(url)")
        }
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        expect.fulfill()
    }  


    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(1000, handler: nil)
    // Test: output file should exist.
}
```

Comment: Hi couch developer, I've updated the code to take into account the output results but still have these files with 0 AVFrameCount. They all print as 0 though 5 out of 6 actually do have content. Am I forgetting anything here?

Comment: Hi Couch developer, works very well. I will make a reference to this post to the other questions as it falls in the same category. Thanks, I learned a lot about creating own delegation internally.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, check the result of the call to `synth.startSpeakingString(name, toURL: URL)`, which can return `false` if the synthesiser could not start speaking. If it fails, find out why, or just retry it.

Plus, add `[NSSpeechSynthesiserDelegate][1]`, and look for the `speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:` callbacks there. When the synthesiser thinks it has finished speaking, check the file size. If it is zero, retry the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do have the delegate methods which I use just to check if the synthesis was successful, but didn't look into it more for exposing any particular error type on it. I'll get my head around completion blocs after this one :)